# Display only date in Session["DateOfBirth"] Asp.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session-cookies, datetime-format

`Session["DateOfBirth"]` is collecting datetime from database (SQL using Entity Framework) but I only want to show date not time.

Here is my code:

View model class:

```
[Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Date of Birth required")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public string dob { get; set; }
```

Controller class:

```
Session["dob"] = umail.u_dob;
```

Index view:

```
<div class="col">
  <h6>Date of Birth</h6>
  <p class=" ">@Session["dob"]</p>
</div>
```

Output screen:

[image]

Comment: See [Custom date and time format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings), you can display it whatever you want but you should persist/store/track a DateTime instance instead of a string.

Comment: Why are you storing this value in the Session rather than in the Model that you pass to your View?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

below code is Working in my case.
use this code in controller

```
Session["dob"] = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["dob"].ToString()).ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: A date value should be stored as a DateTime until the last possible moment (presentation in a view). Storing it as a string in Session violates that.

Comment: It is working in my case, if you know any other approach then kindly suggest me.

Comment: I didn't say it wouldn't work. The proper thing to do with a date value is to store it as a DateTime until you actually need to display it. That avoids unnecessary conversions, and provides the maximum amount of flexibility. There's no good reason to do anything else, especially in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ToShortDateString() by casting your Session variable:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(Session["dob"].ToString()).ToShortDateString()
```

Another option would be to create a new property in your View Model only for viewing:

```
[Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Date of Birth required")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
public string dob {
  get;
  set;
}

[Display(Name = "Date of Birth")]
public string formattedDob {
  get {
    DateTime dateResult;
    
    if (DateTime.TryParse(dob, out dateResult)) {
      return dateResult.ToShortDateString();
    }
    
    return "";
  }
}
```

Comment: it is Working
Session["dob"] = Convert.ToDateTime(Session["dob"].ToString()).ToShortDateString();

Answer (score -2):

Try this in the controller:

```
Session["dob"] = umail.u_dob.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Comment: it is not working...
.ToString is not working and gives error

Comment: A date value should be stored as a DateTime until the last possible moment (presentation in a view). Storing it as a string in Session violates that.